# Trying to locate 404 Error running python-flask with bootstrap

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

i am building a webpage application using Flask, Jinja2 and Bootstrap. When running the app i get this error:

```
* Running on http://localhost:53293/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2015 19:33:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2015 19:33:56] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The app is based on the Visual Studio 2015rc python template `Flask Web Project` which worked fine.

None of my changes included a favicon, i searched the complete project including external files for `favicon, icon, .ico` but found nothing.

Does someone have an idea how this error could be caused or how to locate the code requesting the favicon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers always try to find a favicon for a site by looking in a standard location, `/favicon.ico`. You did nothing wrong here.

You could of course include serve a file at that location, if you so wish.

Comment: Worked using this Code: `import os
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')` from [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/favicon/)

Answer (score 3):

Add an icon to use as your favorite icon (my_favicon.png in this example) in the static/images folder.

Option 1 (Simple and solves the problem). Add to your routes:

```py
from flask import (url_for, current_app as app)

# favicon
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return url_for('static', filename='/images/my_favicon.png')
```

Option 2: (more general, use solution suggested in the [flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/favicon/?highlight=favicon) using `send_from_directory` as Niels also suggests.

Note: If you want to actually serve the icon and have it show up in the browser tab, add the following to your base template:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/my_favicon.png') }}">
```

Comment: The snippet given above by Niels is more consistent (if the file is a png the path should serve a png too). Overall, url routing should be generalized enough to serve static content. Avoid dedicated one only for a single file.